# Can I register/install Search.CollatorDSO.1 manually

Tags: c#, oledb, windows-search

I'm currently trying to search through some indexed files using the windows.search service.
My problem is that windows search cannot be installed on the web server because its a 'web edition'.
Error message received is:

> Search.CollatorDSO.1 provider is not registered on the local machine

However the index that I'm searching is on another server which does have windows search installed and I'm querying it remotely. This was all working fine in development but only because I have windows.search installed on my dev box.

My question is whether it's possible to get the provider to run on the web server seeing as it's not querying an index on itself.

I'm looking for a way to manually register Search.CollatorDSO.1 on the webserver. Either install or as a dll I can drop in the bin of the web application. So far I've found no reference on how to do this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see the answer found on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23742531/147637

Answer (score 0):

After lots of digging around, the answer has been found.

Downloading and installing Windows Search Server does not install the OLE DB provider. Neither does installing the Windows SDK. The provider is installed when the Windows Search Service is installed.

On Win7/8 desktop OS, this is installed be default (I believe). On server, you have to enable the feature.

[image]

Comment: Any full source code sample in ***C#*** using **Windows Search Service** ?