# How can I search content of pdf files in a C# App using OLE DB MSIDXS provider on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, search, full-text-search, oledb

I just started learning C# and I'm currently trying to solve a problem with a C# desktop app which used the windows search index (MSIDXS) as a provider with OLE DB on Windows 7. After the OS changed to Windows 10 it's no longer working and throwing the exception:

> The 'MSIDXS' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Apparently this method is no longer possible on Windows 10 and only works on XP, Vista, 7 and Server 2003. With Windows 10 it changed to something else and I just can't find a proper documentation/ tutorials on how to do the search when running on a Windows 10 OS.

I found a lot of help and tutorials to realise it the way it is now (with OLE DB and MSIDXS) but nothing to make it work on a Win 10 system.
However, on various other questions and threads regarding the same or similar topic people stated that you can use a different provider such as:

```
Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;
```

Which is not working either. The Error message in this case is:

> Error E_FAIL(0x80004005) in IErrorInfo.GetDescription.

Some people said you have to use third party libraries such as iTextSharp or PDFBox and so on, but these suggestions are from 2006 at best and as I already stated, the app used to work without these and only used the MSIDXS provider.

So I just wanted to ask, if any one has a solution or an idea to fix this problem or for a workaraound.

Comment: You did [enable the search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574189/microsoft-search-service-is-there-an-ole-db-provider-alternate-index-server)? Did you try your app when build as 32-bits ? And build as 64-bits? Any differences?

Comment: @rene: Yes, I did enable the search feature (services.msc -> Windows Search). And running the app as x86 or x64 makes no difference.

Comment: You run it under a normal user account?

Comment: @rene: I did run it as a non-admin and as a admin. No differences.

Comment: I can only suggest to get [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see if it is indeed a COM registration failure due to missing registry keys and/or some fill access issue.

Comment: @rene: Well, thanks for your help first of all but I dont think this is a matter, since more than juse one PC ran the application. If there is a missing registry key it would be highly unlikely to be missing on all those Desktops. I will still give it a try.